# CSS - How to make responsive slider according to this design

Tags: html, css, reactjs, vue.js, responsive

I want to make a responsive sidebar according to this design

[image]

[image]

https://www.figma.com/file/XL2vgu8gUGkZJeYgf80jS0/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1

**my main goal is to attach "< 4/12 >" functionality and make it responsive**

here is my code: **https://jsfiddle.net/yg8rwbju/1/**

```
enter code here
```

*it would be great if it can be completed without any extra library*

Answer (score 0):

Makes 1 column

```
.slider {display: grid; grid-template-columns: 100%; gap: 0 14px;}
```

To hide and toggle, you can add extra class.

```
<div class="slider__element content">
```

Hide 3rd and further elements with nth-child pseudo.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.content:nth-child(n + 3){
   display: none;
 }
}
```

I suggest you to mobile-first styling. First, style it for mobile and then style it for desktop. It is good to handle mobile styling issues.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){}
```